# Can i have a multiple foreign key from array on SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have an array full of id's and all id's are foreign key. I give an example of my tables.

I have **store table** in my db like this:

```
st_id   store_name     tags   
st1     store1         ["t1","t2","t3"] 
st2     store2         ["t1","t4"]
st3     store3         ["t3","t5"]
```

and **tag table** like this

```
tag_id   tag_name
t1       tag1
t2       tag2
t3       tag3
t4       tag4
t5       tag5
```

Now i have to choose all store name that have t1 tag like:

`t1 : st1, st2`
`t2 : st1`
`t3 : st1, st3`

How can i select multiple foreign key inside of array? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: This is why it's not a good idea to store comma separated values in columns

Comment: I agree with e4c5, dont do this

Comment: Bad practice. Why not create a separate table with the tag names and the `store ID` that each tag belongs to... then work your way from there..

Comment: I absolutely agree with you guys, but unfortunately my companies developer created like that :( then a got the job and now i have to solve. BTW thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Some RDBMSs have limited support for arrays, but to my knowledge MySQL isn't really one of them.

The normalized design for this data would be a many-to-many design using a junction table like so:

```
store table
st_id   store_name
st1     store1
st2     store2
st3     store3

store_tag table
st_id   tag_id   
st1     t1
st1     t2
st1     t3
st2     t1
st2     t4
st3     t3
st3     t5


tag table
tag_id   tag_name
t1       tag1
t2       tag2
t3       tag3
t4       tag4
t5       tag5
```

You could then do this for a list of all stores with their tags:

```
SELECT s.st_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) AS tags
FROM store s
JOIN store_tag st
    ON st.st_id = s.st_id
JOIN tag t
    ON t.tag_id = st.tag_id
GROUP BY st_id;
```

Or, this if you want a list of all stores with a specific tag name:

```
SELECT s.st_id
FROM store s
JOIN store_tag st
    ON st.st_id = s.st_id
JOIN tag t
    ON t.tag_id = st.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name = 'tag1';
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach to this is, as others have mentioned, to have a pivot table. Your new layout would be like this:

**Store table:**

```
st_id   store_name    
st1     store1        
st2     store2        
st3     store3
```

**Tag Table:**

```
tag_id   tag_name
t1       tag1
t2       tag2
t3       tag3
t4       tag4
t5       tag5
```

**tag_store(Tag-to-Store Pivot Table):**

```
tag_id   std_id
std1     t1
std1     t2
std1     t3
std2     t1
std2     t4
std3     t3
std3     t5
```

This will result in a query like this
    SELECT store_name, tag_name 
    FROM store JOIN tag_store ON tag_store.std_id=store.id 
               JOIN tag ON tag.tag_id=tag_store.tag_id;

If you are using mysql, you could get all of the tags in a single list per store_name by using group_concat:
    SELECT store_name, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM store JOIN tag_store ON tag_store.std_id=store.id 
               JOIN tag ON tag.tag_id=tag_store.tag_id
    GROUP BY store_name;